# Append class records to a list

Tags: python, list, class

I load a row of data in a class, row by row with a loop.  I'd like to append each row to a list.

```
class Biz:
def __init__(self, dba_name, legal_name):
    self.dba_name = dba_name
    self.legal_name = legal_name

MasterList = []

File_From_Excel = pd.read_excel('C:\file.xlsx')

for index, row in File_From_Excel.iterrows():
    record = Biz(row['Field 1'], row['Field 2'])
    MasterList.append(record)
    print(MasterList)
```

When I run code like this, I do not get an error, but I get info like this printed:
"[<**main**.Biz object at 0x0C11BFB0>, <**main**.Biz object at 0x00BDED50>]"

I'm a newbie and I haven't figured out how to overcome this one.  Thank you!

Comment: This seems fine. The "Biz" object are arranged in a list. But you probably wanted something different to happen. What is it?

Comment: Thanks.  With the print command on the last line, I was hoping to see values.  I only see this "<__main__.Biz object at 0x0BC24350>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a list of class instances, so the output is their memory addresses. What you probably want instead is the attributes of these instances. It can be achieved as follows (for illustrative purposes):

```
# this goes at the end of your code, outside of the loop!
print([[record.dba_name, record.legal_name] for record in MasterList])
```

This approach is by no means optimal and and will give you memory issues if there are a lot of elements in `MasterList`. In that case you would want to use either a generator or a class iterator.

**Edit:** Come to think of it, there is no need for a generator here since a simple for loop can iterate over the list:

```
for record in MasterList:
  print([record.dba_name, record.legal_name], end=' ')
```